# sprintf like functionality in Python

Tags: python, string

I would like to create a string buffer to do lots of processing, format and finally write the buffer in a text file using a C-style `sprintf` functionality in Python. Because of conditional statements, I can’t write them directly to the file.

e.g pseudo code:

```
sprintf(buf,"A = %d\n , B= %s\n",A,B)
/* some processing */
sprint(buf,"C=%d\n",c)
....
...
fprintf(file,buf)
```

So in the output file we have this kind of o/p:

```
A= foo B= bar
C= ded
etc...
```

**Edit, to clarify my question:**
`buf` is a big buffer contains all these strings which have formatted using sprintf.
Going by your examples, `buf` will only contain current values, not older ones.
e.g first in `buf` I wrote `A= something ,B= something` later `C= something` was appended in the same `buf`, but in your Python answers `buf` contains only last value, which is not I want - I want `buf` to have all the `printf`s I have done since the beginning, like in `C`.

Comment: That's not the way sprintf() works in C. (It writes the contents at the start of `buf`, not at the end.) It would probably work best to use an array of strings, then join them together before you write to the file.

Comment: @dividebyzero Is this not trivial in Python as it is a general programming language?  For example, see [Michael J. Barber's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18514789/3638059) (posted after your comment).  `def sprintf(buf, fmt, *args): ...`

Comment: @jdk1.0 I don't know what I meant, I was young and naive Python programmer... This question is actually weird because this buffer reuse thing is not that simple, you'd need to increment a pointer with the output of each sprintf call, and this kind of thing is not something you should be worrying about if you're doing Python. Anyway, I'm glad I moved on to Scala and now Julia!

Answer (score 209):

Python has a `%` operator for this.

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = "hello"
>>> buf = "A = %d\n , B = %s\n" % (a, b)
>>> print buf
A = 5
 , B = hello

>>> c = 10
>>> buf = "C = %d\n" % c
>>> print buf
C = 10
```

See this [reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) for all supported format specifiers.

You could as well use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
>>> print "This is the {}th tome of {}".format(5, "knowledge")
This is the 5th tome of knowledge
```

Answer (score 46):

If I understand your question correctly, [format()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#format) is what you are looking for, along with [its mini-language](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Silly example for python 2.7 and up:

```
>>> print "{} ...\r\n {}!".format("Hello", "world")
Hello ...
 world!
```

For earlier python versions: (tested with 2.6.2)

```
>>> print "{0} ...\r\n {1}!".format("Hello", "world")
Hello ...
 world!
```

Comment: You should probably note that that version only works in Python 3.  In Python 2.6, for example, you need to do: `"{0} ...\r\n {1}!".format("Hello", "world")`

Comment: Editing my answer to include that; do not that it also works for python 2.7 though !

Answer (score 27):

I'm not completely certain that I understand your goal, but you can use a `StringIO` instance as a buffer:

```
>>> import StringIO 
>>> buf = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> buf.write("A = %d, B = %s\n" % (3, "bar"))
>>> buf.write("C=%d\n" % 5)
>>> print(buf.getvalue())
A = 3, B = bar
C=5
```

Unlike `sprintf`, you just pass a string to `buf.write`, formatting it with the `%` operator or the `format` method of strings.

You could of course define a function to get the `sprintf` interface you're hoping for:

```
def sprintf(buf, fmt, *args):
    buf.write(fmt % args)
```

which would be used like this:

```
>>> buf = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> sprintf(buf, "A = %d, B = %s\n", 3, "foo")
>>> sprintf(buf, "C = %d\n", 5)
>>> print(buf.getvalue())
A = 3, B = foo
C = 5
```

Comment: +1 for showing me how to use *args with the string formatting operator (%).

Comment: for Python3 use `io.StringIO()` instead

Answer (score 19):

Use the [formatting operator `%`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting):

```
buf = "A = %d\n , B= %s\n" % (a, b)
print >>f, buf
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want something like the python3 print function but to a string:

```py
def sprint(*args, **kwargs):
    sio = io.StringIO()
    print(*args, **kwargs, file=sio)
    return sio.getvalue()
```

```py
>>> x = sprint('abc', 10, ['one', 'two'], {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {1, 2, 3})
>>> x
"abc 10 ['one', 'two'] {'a': 1, 'b': 2} {1, 2, 3}\n"
```

or without the `'\n'` at the end:

```py
def sprint(*args, end='', **kwargs):
    sio = io.StringIO()
    print(*args, **kwargs, end=end, file=sio)
    return sio.getvalue()
```

```py
>>> x = sprint('abc', 10, ['one', 'two'], {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {1, 2, 3})
>>> x
"abc 10 ['one', 'two'] {'a': 1, 'b': 2} {1, 2, 3}"
```

Comment: Don't know why every other answer is avoiding the actual question. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 9):

You can use string formatting:

```
>>> a=42
>>> b="bar"
>>> "The number is %d and the word is %s" % (a,b)
'The number is 42 and the word is bar'
```

But this is removed in Python 3, you should use "str.format()":

```
>>> a=42
>>> b="bar"
>>> "The number is {0} and the word is {1}".format(a,b)
'The number is 42 and the word is bar'
```

Comment: Wrong, it is not removed in Python 3. Python 3.0 said it would be deprecated in 3.1 but I believe that never happened. Using `format()` may be preferable but `%` formatting still exists. (See http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-September/092399.html for some of the reasoning why it was not deprecated)

Answer (score 7):

To insert into a very long string it is nice to use names for the different arguments, instead of hoping they are in the right positions. This also makes it easier to replace multiple recurrences.

```
>>> 'Coordinates: {latitude}, {longitude}'.format(latitude='37.24N', longitude='-115.81W')
'Coordinates: 37.24N, -115.81W'
```

Taken from [Format examples](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#formatexamples), where all the other `Format`-related answers are also shown.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably the closest translation from your C code to Python code.

```
A = 1
B = "hello"
buf = "A = %d\n , B= %s\n" % (A, B)

c = 2
buf += "C=%d\n" % c

f = open('output.txt', 'w')
print >> f, c
f.close()
```

The `%` operator in Python does almost exactly the same thing as C's `sprintf`. You can also print the string to a file directly. If there are lots of these string formatted stringlets involved, it might be wise to use a `StringIO` object to speed up processing time.

So instead of doing `+=`, do this:

```
import cStringIO
buf = cStringIO.StringIO()

...

print >> buf, "A = %d\n , B= %s\n" % (A, B)

...

print >> buf, "C=%d\n" % c

...

print >> f, buf.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread - but there is a new string interpolation "style" - the f'' string formatting construct.

```
a = 5
b = "hello"
buf = f"A = {a:d}\n , B = {b}\n"
```

The F-String (as it is called) is specified in [PEP-498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

Prior to learning of the F-String, I would make calls to format like this:

```
a = 5
b = "hello"
buf = "A = {a:d}\n , B = {b}\n".format( **{ **globals() , **locals() } )
```

According to the PEP-498 documentation, the F-String is available in Python 3.6 or later.

Comment: This style also allows more complex formats such as zero padding, base conversion and float length/precisions, e.g.:

`color=65314`

`opacity=0.2`

`print(f"#{color:06x} at {opacity:4.2f} opacity.")`

`# prints "#00ff22 at 0.20 opacity."`

Answer (score 4):

Something like...

```
greetings = 'Hello {name}'.format(name = 'John')

Hello John
```

Comment: This also printed %s to the screen, which was not expected; but I like that I can add multiple variables with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches are to write to a string buffer or to write lines to a list and join them later.  I think the `StringIO` approach is more pythonic, but didn't work before Python 2.6.

```
from io import StringIO

with StringIO() as s:
   print("Hello", file=s)
   print("Goodbye", file=s)
   # And later...
   with open('myfile', 'w') as f:
       f.write(s.getvalue())
```

You can also use these without a `ContextMananger` (`s = StringIO()`).  Currently, I'm using a context manager class with a `print` function.  This fragment might be useful to be able to insert debugging or odd paging requirements:

```
class Report:
    ... usual init/enter/exit
    def print(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with StringIO() as s:
            print(*args, **kwargs, file=s)
            out = s.getvalue()
        ... stuff with out

with Report() as r:
   r.print(f"This is {datetime.date.today()}!", 'Yikes!', end=':')
```

Answer (score 0):

Even easier than C sprint

```
#compare
s = sprintf(" %03d ", number);  # in other languages

s = " %03d " % number     # in Python

# can even concatenate, without problems

s += " %.3f " % some_decimal
```