# Save what was printed on the screen

Tags: python, output-redirect

Is there any way to save into a variable what `print` sends to the screen, so I will be able to print it back after erasing the screen?

Comment: If you are printing on the screen, you should already have it stored. Can you specify where is the information on the screen from?

Comment: What have you tried? If you show your attempt and circumstances it'll be easier to help.

Comment: What screen are you talking about? Please give more details.

Comment: May be this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309978/sprintf-like-functionality-in-python

Answer (score 3):

Don't know why this question is being downvoted. Anyway, an answer from [Raymond Hettinger on Twitter](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/1030160198600548352), utilises [`contextlib.redirect_stdout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout):

> ```
> with open('help.txt', 'w') as f:
>     with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
>         help(pow)
> ```

Although, in this case the output is being redirected into a file, rather than a variable and is Python3, not 2.7.

From the docs, to capture that in a variable:

> For example, the output of help() normally is sent to sys.stdout. You can capture that output in a string by redirecting the output to an `io.StringIO` object:
>
> ```
> f = io.StringIO()
> with redirect_stdout(f):
>     help(pow)
> s = f.getvalue()
> ```

[This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10743550/1431750) shows another way to do it, and in Python2:

Comment: Great answer, [much to learn](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout): until now I did `print(..., file=f)` by hand.