# Printing a random int

Tags: python

I'm making a story type game and one of the aspects is a pass code that is needed to be put in every game. I want to make the code unique every time, so I used this to generate the numbers: `n1 = random.randint(1,9),n2 = random.randint(1,9),n3 = random.randint(1,9),n4 = random.randint(1,9),n5 = random.randint(1,9)`. With this I have the numbers for the password random everytime. So I also made this to make the person type it out later: `print("Type ["), print(n1), print(n2), print(n3), print(n4), print(n5), print("] to verify as a Human.")`  Gives the error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: I imported all the stuff needed to write this for anyone wanting to know.

Comment: Please post the code in a properly formatted code block. Put triple backtick on the lines before and after the code.

Comment: I might suggest using f-strings.

Comment: You shouldn't have `,` between statements.

Comment: Post the full traceback with the error message.

Comment: How do i post the full code its too long?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Separating assignments with commas is a syntax error. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including complete code, any example input, expected output, and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). You can [edit], and while you're there, please write a more descriptive title. For tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would have had the code just be a 5 digit number to begin with:

```
code = random.randint(11111, 99999)
```

I'm a bit confused with what you are doing in the prints. Are you just trying to print out the code? In that case with your code logic it would be

```
print("Type [", n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, "] to verify as a Human.")
```

or using my code logic and f-strings:

```
print(f"Type [{code}] to verify as a Human.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating 5 int variables, use a loop to build your passcode and `join` it into a string so you can compare it against an `input`:

```
import random

passcode = "".join(str(random.randint(1, 9)) for _ in range(5))
print(f"Type [{passcode}] to verify as a Human.")
if input() == passcode:
    print("welcome, human")
else:
    print("begone, imposter")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ["sprintf"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309978/sprintf-like-functionality-in-python) type way of doing what you want:

```
n = [random.randint(1,9) for _ in range(5)]
printstr='Type [' + '%d'*5 + '] to verify'
print(printstr % tuple(n))
```