# How to log transform values for color in Plotly but to keep original values on colorbar?

Tags: r, plotly, logarithm

I am trying to log transform values that are defining color on a Plotly graph, but I would like to keep original values on the Plotly color bar legend (not log-transformed numbers) in order to improve readability.

Here is the example of what I am trying to do on the mtcars data-set:

```
mtcars %>% plot_ly(x = ~hp, 
               y = ~qsec,                                                                        
               size = ~disp,
               color = ~mpg)
```

and you will get this graph:

[image]

Let's say I want to log transform color variable (mpg) with this code:

```
mtcars %>% plot_ly(x = ~hp, 
               y = ~qsec,                                                                        
               size = ~disp,
               color = ~log(mpg))
```

I will get this graph:
[image]

I am satisfied now with the graph, but now the colorbar on the right is having log() numbers.

My question is: how to log() transform color variable on a graph **but keep the original numbers on the colorbar that are appropriately adjusted to new log colors?**

So, on the one hand, I would like to have the original numbers on the second picture color bar, instead of 2.5, 3 and 3.5, but on the other hand, I would like to keep the color-positions of these numbers as they are on the log scale and without using ggplotly.

Comment: can you say a little more about why ggplotly isn't an option? It's so easy that way (I posted an answer and then deleted it since I saw you didn't want ggplotly ...)

Comment: The problem with ggplotly is that hoover info/text is not so responsive and smooth when sliding between points (or regions on a map made with ggplotly), so it is better to do it directly in plotly.

Comment: In fact, we are looking for the solution in Plotly that is available for Phyton, see here: https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#customizing-tick-text-on-logarithmic-color-bars       If somebody knows how to do this in R?

Comment: good luck ... seems too hard for me to figure out. I would start with `?plotly::layout`, but honestly it doesn't seem too useful: actually, [this](https://plotly.com/r/colorscales/)  and [this](https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/coloraxis/) seem more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similarly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59098804/6530970), this is a matter of using transformed values for the colour bar ticks, but untransformed values as labels.

Here is an option:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

# Define pretty breaks on transformed scale
brks_transformed <- pretty(log10(mtcars$mpg), n = 5)

# Breaks on the untransformed scale
brks_untransformed <- sprintf("%.1f", 10^brks_transformed)

mtcars %>% 
    plot_ly(
        x = ~hp, y = ~qsec, size = ~ disp, fill = ~ "",
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "markers",
        marker = list(
            color = ~ log10(mpg),
            line = list(width = 0),
            colorbar = list(
                tickmode = "array",
                ticktext = brks_untransformed,
                tickvals = brks_transformed)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks: can you explain more this part:                                                         `brks_untransformed <- sprintf("%.1f", 10^brks_transformed)`                                          What to put if you want to sqrt() or ordinary log() transformation?                                     And is it possible with sprntif() to add decimal points between numbers for large numbers, eg. 1,000,000 and add character, eg. $ at the end?

Comment: @kosk The first step is to define the transformation & inverse transformation. I've shown you how to do it for a log-transformed scale; if you want a different transformation, you follow the same recipe. For `sqrt`, you'd have e.g. `brks_transformed <- pretty(sqrt(mtcars$mpg), n = 5)` and `brks_untransformed <- sprintf("%.1f", brks_transformed^2)` as well as `color = ~ sqrt(mpg)` in the `marker` argument to `plot_ly`. I assume you're familiar with`sprintf` (see `?sprintf` for more details); you can use`sprintf` in any way you like: more decimal points, dollar sign as a suffix etc.

Comment: PS. You seem to have a Python background, and [sadly `sprintf` is absent in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309978/sprintf-like-functionality-in-python) (but has the somwhat similar `%` operator). But if you're familiar with C/C++, R's `sprintf` offers similar functionality.

Comment: You used in example log10 in `brks_transformed <- pretty(log10(mtcars$mpg), n = 5)` and then to untransform the scale you use 10^brks_transformed.                                   But which number to use for untransform if you only do log (so NOT log10, but only log)?                                                                                                                  And if you could show how to add thousand separator and a sign of dollar at the end with sprintf. To be hones ?sprintf does not help and neither I see the answer anywhere on the net.

Comment: @kosk `log10` is the base-10 logarithm, `log` is base `e` (i.e. `exp(1)`). Adding a dollar sign is trivial: for example, have a look at `sprintf("$%s", 10)`. There are quite a few posts here on SO around formatting numbers with thousands separators, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465941/format-number-in-r-with-both-comma-thousands-separator-and-specified-decimals). One example: `sprintf("$%s", formatC(10000, format = "f", big.mark = ",", digits = 0))`.